# SQL Server 2008 R2 but still 4GB DB size limit?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I just upgraded my SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2008 R2. I tried to import a DB which was 7GB in size and the Management Studio still gives me the 4GB limit error. When loading the Management Studion it says R2, so that seems to work.

Ideas?

Comment: According to the blurb, the new limit for express (which I assume is what you're using, the other versions have vastly higher limits) is 10GB - http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/

Comment: Yes, thats correct, but I am still limited to 4GB ...

Comment: What does SELECT @@VERSION say please? Management studio can be a different version to the SQL Server engine

Comment: Ahaaa, it says: **Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64)   Jul  9 2008 14:17:44   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: )**

Thats not correct I guess ... how do I switch the engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like rather than upgrading the old instance, you installed a new instance of R2 and left the old one running as well; check Services to see if there are multiple SQL Server entries and what the instance names are; then make sure you connect to the R2 one with SSMS.